# Better Way to Prove this

Tags: graphing-functions, radicals, alternative-proof

I was trying to prove that $c$ was of form $2p-1$ knowing that $c^2$ was of form $4k+1$. Now, the solution is obviously $\sqrt{4k+1}$, but knowing that both $c$ and $k$ were integers, I tried to figure out what form $c$ could take. I went to Desmos and graphed the function $f(k)=\sqrt{4k+1}$, and the first ten points with integer coordinates I got were $(0, 1), (2,3), (6,5), (12,7), (20,9), (30,11), (42,13), (56,15), (72,17),$ and $(90,19)$. My computer quickly figured out that the pattern for the $x$-coordinate, with the point number being $p$, was $p^2-p$. The pattern for the $y$-coordinate is obviously $2p-1$. Thus, I concluded that k must be of form $p^2-p$ and $c$ must be of form $2p-1$.

My question is: Is there an algebraic way to do what I did? If so, how would I go about it?

Comment: From the title: "this Equation".  What equation?  It is entirely unclear what problem you started with, what part of your text describes scratch work, and what part of your text answers the problem (if any part does).

Comment: $4(p^2-p)+1=(2p-1)^2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Square root of an odd perfect square is odd. Every odd number is of the form $2p-1$ for some integer $p$.